# system() in r always returns error but bash terminal() works

Tags: r, bash

I would like to rename files based on list 'mappingFile.csv'. Actually, I do most of the work in r so tried to run it in rstudio but it returns error, while bash terminal does work as expected.

```
y <- 'awk -F',' 'system("mv " $1 " " $2)' mappingFile.csv'
cat(y)
system(y)
#It return error
Error: unexpected symbol in "y <- "awk -F',' 'system("mv"
```

Another example when I try to download some files from r using system command

```
y <- 'gdc-client download -m manifest.txt'
system(y)
#it also return error
sh: 1: x: not found Warning message: In system("x") : r
```

Only some bash commands run in system or system2 in r.

Can someone suggest How do I fix it?

Comment: What OS are you using? The quotes for the first `y` example don't look correct. You are mixing single and double quotes and what you have isn't value R code.  You can use something like `y <- r"(awk -F',' 'system("mv " $1 " " $2)' mappingFile.csv)"` to get a valid string. You seem to have cut off the error in the second example. What's the full error message?

Comment: The `y` line is itself having some errors

Comment: @MrFlickit it is ubuntu 20.04. Yes, it is working but May I ask, what is the purpose of putting r before double quote? would you please explain

Comment: It the "raw" string syntax. More info here: https://mpopov.com/blog/2020/05/22/strings-in-r-4.x/

Comment: @MrFlick Thank you so much dear for your valuable insight, I will read the shared link. actually, the second one is working after restarting the rstudio. I just opened it to check the full error message and it working. Thanks you dear

Comment: @akrun Thanks bro, actually MrFlick solution helped. Yes, the second one is working after restarting rstudio . Thanks to both of you

Comment: `system2` is the recommended way of calling the OS, not `system`. It allows the user to separate command from arguments.

Comment: @RuiBarradas, but it doesn't protect well: `system2` only `shQuote`s the command itself, none of the arguments; for those, it just `paste`s them together with spaces. Both are horribly broken in my view, I strongly recommend the use of the [`ps`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ps/index.html) package for any "real" (safe) process calls.

Comment: (All `system2` does is combine `command` and `args` into `command <- paste(c(shQuote(command), env, args), collapse = " ")`, and then `.Internal(system(command, flag, f, stdout, stderr, timeout))`. Unfortunately very broken.)